# Как установить ubuntu на странное устройство на архитектуре arm?

Tags: ubuntu, arm

Есть [устройство](http://ru.aliexpress.com/item/Vensmile-Android-Mini-PC-MK809-Quad-Core-RK3288-Cortext-A17-1-8GHz-HDMI-TV-Stick-4K/32437370470.html?adminSeq=202344923&shopNumber=223881), которое просто грузится с черным экраном. Скорее всего, что-то поломалось либо поломали. В нем есть разъем для sdcard. Суть такова, что нужно установить ubuntu. 
Нашел [статью](http://blog.geekbuying.com/index.php/2014/08/11/how-to-flash-stock-firmware-for-rk3288-tv-box-tablet-pc-newest-flash-tools-download-available/) по которой пробовал вернуть все как было. Но безуспешно пока что. Может не тот дистрибутив или еще что-то.
Полного сброса настроек я на устройстве не нашел.

Comment: А может там загрузчик сдох и тогда JTAG нужен...

Comment: Может быть и сдох, я не знаю. Можно немного поподробнее про JTAG. Буду весьма благодарен.

Comment: Вам ссылку на википедию дать?

Comment: Как вы пытаетесь установить линукс в устройство которое требует родную прошивку на андроид? Не путайте одно с другим, хоть они и вышли из одного. Прочитайте повторно статью, что требуется для перепрошивки, попробуйте, если не поучится то вам на 4pda

Answer (score 1):

Андроид менее требовательный к cpu, qpu, и другим фитчам. Ваше устройство использует 100% проприетарные модули, дрова и тд, не факт что они завидутся у вас. Это архитектура arm, весь софт только процах Intel, amd (у него есть совместимость с Intel), пример: не находилось wine :).

Вот мне известные дистрибутивы которые имеют совместимость с arm.

1. **Debian** https://www.debian.org/ports/arm/
2. **Arch linux** https://archlinuxarm.org/
3. **Ubuntu** не находилось, но существует **Ubuntu touch** (мобильная, под **android** портируется самостоятельно) https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Touch